# How/why is the rust compiler here ignoring that a template argument should have static lifetime?

Tags: rust

Why does this rust code compile?

```
use std::fmt::Display;

fn g<T: 'static + Display>(t: T) {
    println!("{}", t);
}

fn t() {
    let x: i32 = 12;
    g(x);
}

fn main() {
    t();
}
```

Certainly in the function `t()` the local variable `x` is not static, yet the template specification of `g` seems to the demand that it must be. What am I misunderstanding?

For context: the example above is clearly very contrived. In a more complicated setting that I am working on, the compiler is forcing me to use `T: 'static` instead of just `T`, but I don't want to use it just for static types. To my surprise however it just also works for non static variables and I am confused...

Comment: The bound `T: 'static` means that `T` only holds references that outlive the `'static` lifetime, not that `T` has to be a `static` item. And because `i32` holds no references at all, this is trivially true.

Comment: @isaactfa Thanks for the answer, that clears it up. Feel free to post as an answer and I will accept if you are interested in fake internet points :)

Comment: See [Common Rust Lifetime Misconceptions](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program) for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bound `T: 'static` means that `T` only holds references that outlive the `'static` lifetime (or more generally, all lifetime parameters on `T` do), not that `T` has to be a static item. And because `i32` holds no references at all, this is trivially true. For reference, see [the Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#lifetime-bounds) and this [handy guide, suggested by kmdreko](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program).

Comment: Thanks. So does this imply that in order to have a &'static T, the T itself must be T: 'static, as otherwise you might hold a static reference to something that perhaps cannot be safely held indefinitely?

Comment: Yes, and in general for `&'a T` `T: 'a` must hold.

Comment: All clear! Thanks again